# Interpretation of number of observations in confusion matrix after k-fold cross validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I completed a 5-fold cross validation and produced a confusion matrix that (I believe) summarizes the results of the 5-fold cv; however, I don't understand why there are only 8 observations in the confusion matrix. My reproducible data set has 10 observations. I did an 80/20 training/testing split...But, I thought the confusion matrix would include all 10 observations, 2 from each test multiplied by the number of folds (5). Why are there only 8?

```
forestcov <- c(45, 67, 35, 67, 12, 43, 75, 8, 34, 46)
numspecies <- c(3, 6, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 5, 3, 4)
outcome <- as.factor(c('no','no','yes','yes','no','yes',
                       'no', 'yes', 'yes','no'))

df <- data.frame(outcome, forestcov, numspecies)
library(caret)

#partition data
set.seed(123) 
index <- createDataPartition(df$outcome, p = .8, list = FALSE, times = 1) 
train_df <- df[index,] 
test_df <- df[-index,] 

#specify training methods
specifications <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, 
                               savePredictions = "all", 
                               classProbs = TRUE) 

#specify logistic regression model
set.seed(1234) 
model1 <- train(outcome ~ forestcov + numspecies, 
                data=train_df,
                method = "glm",
                family = binomial, trControl = specifications)

#produce confusion matrix
confusionMatrix(model1, norm = "none")
```

Comment: With so few cases you shouldn't be doing separate train/test splits. See [this page](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/), for example, which recommends only doing full splits if you have tens of thousands of observations. Otherwise, internal validation (e.g., repeated full cross-validation, or bootstrapping) is the best use of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, model1 never sees the "test" data frame in any way - you pass it the data in train_df, which only contains 8 samples, and you give it the specifications to do 5-fold cross validation data within that training data. There's no reason here to split into the train/test sets up front, as that's what the cross-validation specification is for. In your code, you define the test data in test_df, and then never use those 2 samples for anything at all! You should be running the cross-validated training routine on the full data in df - you're effectively running 5-fold cross-validation on your 8 "training" samples, and holding out 2 samples as an entirely independent test set which aren't used in the cross-validation.

Comment: I think I am following. My cross validation has basically severed off 20% of my data and created training and test folds using only 80% of my data. Thus 20% of each fold would = 1.6, multiplied by 5 folds would equal the 8 observations in the confusion matrix. Thank you for that explanation! How do I include all of the data in the cross validation? My goal was to create 5 stratified folds and run the cross validation on my entire data set. I understand the problem, but I am unsure as to what part of the code needs to be tweaked to include everything in the cv.

Comment: @Chullah Instead of passing a subset of the data (train_df) to the cross-validation train() function, just pass the whole dataset (df). It should internally split the data into 5 folds. You're currently telling the train() function to cross-validate over the 8 samples in train_df, but you need to give it all 10 samples in df.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I appreciate your assistance!